# Some Images and Videos Not Displayed in Gallery

Tags: gallery

On my Lenovo Vibe P1, photos and videos I download or receive via apps (Whatsapp, Xender, etc.) are not displayed in the Gallery, but photos and videos taken with the camera and screen shots are. How can I get all photos and videos to appear properly in the Gallery?

Answer (score -1):

try to change the location of the videos/photos by cutting them from their previous folder and then pasting to a new location/folder.